# Managing Concurrent Data Storage for Cucumber BDD Tests in a Parallel Execution Environment

Tags: java, testng, appium-android, cucumber-java

Issue Summary:
In our Cucumber BDD framework using Java, we've encountered a conflict while attempting to run multiple test cases in parallel. Each test case relies on storing raw data in a shared data structure (like a Map Interface). However, due to parallel execution, different threads end up containing conflicting values, leading to inaccurate test results.

Context:

We are utilizing the Cucumber BDD framework with Java for our test automation.
Each test case involves storing raw data in a shared data structure, specifically a Map Interface.
The goal is to parallelize test execution to improve efficiency and reduce test execution time.
However, the parallel execution is causing conflicts in the shared data structure due to different threads accessing and modifying the data concurrently.
Request for Assistance:

How can we organize the storage of the Map Interface to ensure that each thread has its own isolated data for each test case?
What approaches or best practices can we adopt to manage data storage efficiently and handle concurrent access during parallel test execution?
Potential Approaches:

ThreadLocal with ConcurrentHashMap:
Utilize ThreadLocal along with a ConcurrentHashMap to create thread-specific data storage, ensuring each test case has its independent data map.

InheritableThreadLocal:
Explore using InheritableThreadLocal to allow child threads to inherit the initial data map from the parent thread, providing a hierarchical approach to thread-specific data.

Custom Data Structure with Synchronization:
Consider a synchronized data structure (e.g., synchronized map) to handle concurrent access, ensuring each thread can access its test data in a synchronized manner.

Database or External Storage:
Evaluate the option of storing test data in a database or an external storage system, allowing each thread to retrieve and update its specific test data without conflicts.

Request for Guidance:
We are seeking advice, best practices, or code examples on implementing the chosen approach to handle concurrent data storage effectively during parallel test execution in our Cucumber BDD framework using Java.

**1. Thread-Safe Data Structure Initialization:**
Initialize a ThreadLocal variable to hold the Map for each thread. This ensures that each thread has its own isolated Map.

```
public class TestData {
    private static ThreadLocal<Map<String, Object>> testData = ThreadLocal.withInitial(HashMap::new);

    public static Map<String, Object> getTestData() {
        return testData.get();
    }

    public static void setTestData(Map<String, Object> data) {
        testData.set(data);
    }

    public static void clearTestData() {
        testData.remove();
    }
}
```

**2. Updating Raw Data for Each Test Case:**
Whenever a step updates raw data, it should use the ThreadLocal Map to store data specific to the current test case.

```
public class YourStepDefinitions {
    @Given("some condition")
    public void givenSomeCondition() {
        // Retrieve the thread-specific Map for this test case
        Map<String, Object> testData = TestData.getTestData();

        // Add/update raw data for this test case
        testData.put("key", "value");
    }

    // Other step definitions
}
```

**3. Usage in Cucumber Runner:**
When running the tests in parallel, ensure that each thread operates on its own test data using the ThreadLocal Map and this is done for the Hooks class.
`public class RunCucumberTests {
@Before
public void setUp() {
// Initialize thread-specific test data
TestData.setTestData(new HashMap<>());
}

```
@After
public void tearDown() {
    // Clear thread-specific test data after each scenario
    TestData.clearTestData();
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

To share data between steps you'll want to use dependency injection. Cucumber supports a few frameworks, but picocontainer is the easiest to get started with.

```xml
<dependencies>
  [...]
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  [...]
</dependencies>
```

So suppose you have a class you want to share between different step definition classes. Note the absence of static fields, thread locals or concurrent data structures - you don't need them, `cucumber-picocontainer` care of that.

```java
import java.util.List;

public class Belly {

    private final List<String> contents;

    public void setContents(List<String> contents){
        this.contents = contents;
    }
    
    public List<String> getContents(){
        return contents;
    }
}
```

Then you declare `Belly` as a constructor argument for your step definitions.

```java
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;

import java.util.Collections;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class StepDefinition {

    private final Belly belly;

    public StepDefinitions(Belly belly) {
        this.belly = belly;
    }

    @Given("I have {int} {word} in my belly")
    public void I_have_n_things_in_my_belly(int n, String what) {
        belly.setContents(Collections.nCopies(n, what));
    }

    @Then("there are {int} cukes in my belly")
    public void checkCukes(int n) {
        assertEquals(belly.getContents(), Collections.nCopies(n, "cukes"));
    }
}
```

When running your steps, Cucumber will when creating an instance of the `StepDefinition` class also create an instance of `Belly`. This instance is unique for each scenario and any data stored in it won't leak to the next scenario.

See: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-picocontainer for more.

Comment: Not working as it still taking the same set of login credentials for all the test cases executing in parallel.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing something wrong. But hard to say what that is.

Comment: can we connect somewhere e.g. Google Meet and MS Teams etc.