# How to quit specific WebDriver instance in @After

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am trying to run some Cucumber feature files in parallel using the maven-surefire-plugin with parallelisation configured as follows in pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Each step definition class has its own specific instance of `WebDriver` with the use of `TestSetUp` as follows:

```java
public class TestSetUp {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    public TestSetUp() {
        driver = createChromeDriver();
    }

    private WebDriver createWebDriver() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        return driver;
    }
}
```

And the step definition classes would look like this:

```java
public class Test_A {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void beforeScenario() {
        setUp = new TestSetUp();
        driver = setUp.driver;

    }

    @When("The user navigates to the site")
    public void openSite() {
        driver.get("https://www.examplesite.com")

    @And("The user executes task on the site")
    public void executeTask() {
        // Logic for executing tasks on the webpage via the specific WebDriver instance
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.close();
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this without duplication of the @Before and @After hooks, while being able to use a specific instance of `WebDriver` for each step definition file, as I need to run multiple feature files (hence multiple step definition classes) in parallel.

Comment: This answer also applies to parallel execution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77150309/managing-concurrent-data-storage-for-cucumber-bdd-tests-in-a-parallel-execution/77150404#77150404

Comment: And it would probably be good to not have a 1-to-1 relationship between classes and features.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje What do you mean by 1-to-1 relationship between classes and features?

Answer (score 1):

Put your @Before and @After in TestSetUp. They don't need to be in each test. They will get called before and after each test is run anyway. That will prevent a lot of code duplication.

Also, in @After it should be `driver.quit()` not `driver.close()`. `driver.close()` just closes the current tab where `driver.quit()` actually fully quits/closes the browser/driver instance.

Comment: Would the correct instance of `@Before` and `@After` be called for each test running in parallel if I put it in TestSetUp? And would I need to have TestSetUp stored in the glue for the test runner?

Comment: Yes, it should all work. You can easily test it by making the changes and then running a suite with a few tests.

Comment: I tried it and seems like the driver does not quit. I tried adding TestSetUp to the glue of the runner but it doesn't work too. Weird maybe it has to be in the step definition file.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje would you know anything about this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with cucumber but my projects are C#/NUnit and I use this approach and it works well... has for years. Maybe add a logging line in the `@Before` and `@After` methods to make sure they are being called? That might help diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Ken I don't have time to write a comprehensive answer. But start with steps, hooks and web driver in one class. Debug it. Get it to work. The if you want to have multiple classes use dependency injection to share data. Get it to work. Do not use static. Then try and run in parallel. If you did all the previous steps right, it will work.